# Select Option only filling in first table row

Tags: php

In my program I build a table from data from a MySql Database.

```
        <?php  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    extract($row);?>
    <td width="5">   <input name="record_id" hidden value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"></td>
    <td width="75"> <input name="timeneeded" readonly value="<?php echo $row['time_needed']?>"></td>
    <td width="75"> <input name="dateneeded" readonly value="<?php echo $row['date_needed']?>"></td>
    <td width="100"> <input name="firstname" readonly value="<?php echo $row['first_name']?>"></td>
    <td width="100"> <input name="lastname" readonly value="<?php echo $row['last_name']?>"></td>
    <td width="120"> <input name="pickup" readonly value="<?php echo $row['pickup_location']?>"></td>"
    <td width="100"> <input name="dropoff" readonly value="<?php echo $row['destination']?>"></td>"
    <td width='125' align='left'>
    <select size='1' name='assignDrivers' onChange=showDrivers(this.value)>
    <option>Select Driver</option>
    <?php while(list($username)=mysqli_fetch_row($result1)) {
        echo "<option value=\"".$username."\">".$username."</option>";
     }
     ?>
    </select> <input id="drivertouse" name='driver_name' size='15' style='font-weight: 700' value=<?php echo "\"$username\""; ?>> </td>
```

Everything pulls fine, and on the first row, it pulls the list of drivers, however it doesn't pull them for subsequent rows.  It only shows the 'Select Drivers'

Any help would be appreciated,
TIA

Comment: What difference is list and extract row? What is $result1?

Comment: $result1 is the result of a query on a table

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is at `list($username)`, you should just be able to do this:

```
while($username = mysqli_fetch_row($result1)) {
   echo "<option value=\"".$username."\">".$username."</option>";
}
```

The `$username` variable will be reset as part of the loop so you shouldn't need to use `list()`.

Comment: Still only puts the list in the first row and now returns instead of the info, a list with array, array, array, etc

Comment: Can you please send more code? - What is $result1? and What is stored in $username?. With these infos a solution is very likely.

Comment: Hans, what finally worked was to put the results of the query into an array and then loop through the array for the select statement.  I appreciate your help, it pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Nice to hear that it is over

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $the_drivers = ""; // Initialize the drivers variable

    while(list($username)=mysqli_fetch_row($result1)) {

        $the_drivers .= "<option value='" . $username . "'>" . $username . "</option>";
    }

    if(isset($the_drivers)){

        echo $the_drivers;
    }
?>
```

**Version 2** As Spholt suggested earlier, which I believe strongly, the list() function in there is also a problem. This version 2 removes that list(). I don't know what is $result1(my assumption is that it is a database query). That said, I don't know the column name of $username(I have just imagined it to be username. If it is not replace the correct name in $username_row['username'].

```
<?php
    $the_drivers = ""; // Initialize the drivers variable

    while($username_row=mysqli_fetch_row($result1)) {

    $username = $username_row['username'];

        $the_drivers .= "<option value='" . $username . "'>" . $username . "</option>";
    }

    if(isset($the_drivers)){

        echo $the_drivers;
    }
?>
```

Comment: That had an interesting result, it return enough name for every row but again it placed them in the pulldown for the first row only

Comment: Sorry. Updated. The loop collects the drivers and has to be dumped outside, after the loop is done.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try later today

Comment: This one got close, all the select lists now show, with what looks like the correct amount of space, (there are only 6 records in the table) but there isn't any data in them, but I can play with this.  There is only one column being pulled from the table and the name is 'username' (which I will change for production, this is in testing)

Answer (score 0):

try this code , I think there is a problem with result1 query itself

```
 <?php  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    extract($row);?>
    <td width="5">   <input name="record_id" hidden value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"></td>
    <td width="75"> <input name="timeneeded" readonly value="<?php echo $row['time_needed']?>"></td>
    <td width="75"> <input name="dateneeded" readonly value="<?php echo $row['date_needed']?>"></td>
    <td width="100"> <input name="firstname" readonly value="<?php echo $row['first_name']?>"></td>
    <td width="100"> <input name="lastname" readonly value="<?php echo $row['last_name']?>"></td>
    <td width="120"> <input name="pickup" readonly value="<?php echo $row['pickup_location']?>"></td>"
    <td width="100"> <input name="dropoff" readonly value="<?php echo $row['destination']?>"></td>"
    <td width='125' align='left'>
    <select size='1' name='assignDrivers' onChange=showDrivers(this.value)>
    <option>Select Driver</option>
while($username = mysqli_fetch_row($result1)) {
foreach($username as $user){
   echo "<option value=\"".$user."\">".$user."</option>";
}
}
?>
    </select> <input id="drivertouse" name='driver_name' size='15' style='font-weight: 700' value=<?php echo "\"$username\""; ?>> </td>
```

Comment: The query is pulling the correct information - This returned the exact same results as the original code.  The list is only showing up in the first row.